# Using apostrophes instead of underscores for numeric literal

Tags: parsing, literals

For a custom language parser (math equations with units) I want to match

```
1'000'000
```

instead of

```
1_000_000
```

for numeric literals, but I cannot find a single use case out there in which this convention was used.

Is there a special reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not seen it used in numbers, either, and I've seen a lot of languages.

The [JOVIAL language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JOVIAL), used for defense software for the US Air Force from about 1960 thru the late 1980s (and still present in a large number of legacy systems) uses  a tick mark as a break character in identifiers.

The presumably standard reason for not using tick marks like this in more modern languages is that it is often used as a delimiter for single character literals, e.g.,  'a', 'z' as in the C language.  (PHP and other langauges have string literals, not just character literals, of different types, er, capabilities based on the type of quote character that surrounds the string body).

There's no reason you can't do this.  But it violates the principle of "least surprise" for most users.   And if you have no really good reason to do that, you shouldn't do that, because it just makes acceptance of your tool harder.

I'd stick with "__" as a break character in numbers.  People using Ada are certainly used to this, and those using langauges with "_" as break in identifiers won't be very surprised.